# Pandas replace with string and integers - incorrect behavior?

Tags: python, pandas, debugging

I encountered a potentially incorrect behavior of pandas `.replace()` function, for strings and integers. If the dataframe has both 0 (integer) and '0' (strings) then replace '0' affects both strings and integers.
Here's how it goes:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers' : [0, 1, 2, 0], 'strings' : ['0', 1, 2, '0']})
```

To check that it's indeed the correct setup:

```
In [2]: df.dtypes
Out [2]:
numbers     int64
strings    object
dtype: object
```

And check individual values:

```
In [3]: type(df['numbers'][0])
Out[3]: numpy.int64
In [4]: type(df['strings'][0])
Out[4]: str
```

Now, do replace:

```
In [5]: df.replace(to_replace='0', value=np.NaN, inplace=True)
In [6]: df.head()
Out[6]: 
   numbers  strings
0      NaN      NaN
1        1        1
2        2        2
3      NaN      NaN
```

As you can see, it replaced both strings and integers, however it should have worked only on the strings. If we try the same on integers, it works correctly:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers' : [0, 1, 2, 0], 'strings' : ['0', 1, 2, '0']})
...: df.replace(to_replace=0, value=np.NaN, inplace=True)
...: print df.head()
Out [7]:   
   numbers strings
0      NaN       0
1        1       1
2        2       2
3      NaN       0
```

Is this the correct behavior or should I report a bug? I'm using pandas 0.19.0.

Update: Bug reported and confirmed. @nickil-maveli provided the workaround that works in the meantime:
`df.replace(to_replace=['0'], value=[np.NaN], inplace=True)`

Comment: this is probably a bug I'd post an issue on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)

Comment: @ozhogin, For now you can use a list to wrap values corresponding to `to_replace` and `value` args, like `df.replace(to_replace=['0'], value=[np.NaN], inplace=True)`. But, yeah this should be sorted out somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug reported and confirmed by developers. @nickil-maveli provided a workaround that works in the meantime: `df.replace(to_replace=['0'], value=[np.NaN], inplace=True)`